# show that $\gcd(m^{n-1}-1,n)>1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $m,n$ be integers greater than $1$ such that
$$n\mid m^{p(n-1)}-1$$
Prove that
$$\gcd(m^{n-1}-1,n)>1$$

My try: Assume  that  prime number $q$ such $q\mid\gcd(m^{n-1}-1,n)$, then
$q\mid m^{n-1}-1$ and $q\mid n$, and if let $d=ord_{m}(q)$, then we have
$$d\mid q-1,\ d\mid n-1$$ Then I can't it. Thanks

Comment: I guess you're missing some detail in the problem. What is the $p$ in the beginning actually doing? I mean like there always exists a prime divisor of $m^{n-1}-1$

Comment: @player3236,sorry,I have edit it,is $n|m^{p(n-1)}-1$

Comment: Now it matches up with https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1185052p5753503 and the 'Lemma' in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h422831p2390634.

Comment: @player3236,Thank you,in the link 1 at last How to use LTE get $n|m^{n-1}-1?$

Answer (score 2):

Take any prime divisor of $n$ like $q$. Then by the hypothesis of the problem $q|m^{p(n-1)}-1$ which means that $Ord_{q}(m)|p(n-1)$. On the other hand, if for such $q$, $Ord_{q}(m)|n-1$, then $m^{n-1}-1$ will be divisible by $q$ and because it also divides $n$ the claim is proven. But if $Ord_{q}(m)\not| n-1$ then clearly $p|Ord_{q}(m)|q-1$ which shows that $p$ divides $q-1$ for all of the prime divisors of $n$ like $q$, and thus by multiplying all of these prime divisors, $n\equiv1 (mod p)$
Now put $n=pk+1$ and go through the same procedure, then this time you will find out that if the claim doesn't hold, all of the prime divisors of $n$ shall be congruent to 1 mod $p^2$ and so shall $n$ itself. Then put $n=p^2k+1$ and go through the same method again. So $n-1$ shall have infinite $p$'s in its prime factorization which is a contradiction if $n$ is not equal to 1.